# How do I tell if a function definition "contains" a symbolic expression?

Tags: variable-definitions

Consider a definition like

```
f[x_] := x[[1]] + x[[3]] + x[[1 + 2]]
```

I want a "`ContainsExpression`" which I can use similarly to this:

```
ContainsExpression[f[x], x[[1]]]
>>> True

ContainsExpression[f[x], x[[2]]]
>>> False

ContainsExpression[f[x], x[[3]]]
>>> True

ContainsExpression[f[x], x[[1 + 2]]]
>>> True

ContainsExpression[f[x], x[[2 + 1]]]
>>> (either False or True is acceptable for me)
```

I've tried `DownValues[f][[1]][[2]]` but it gives me an error because it tries to subscript `x`... I can't figure out how to make Mathematica avoid evaluating the subscripts correctly. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `MenberQ`which fulfills exactly the role your ContainsExpression is assumed to:

```
 f[x_] := x[[1]] + x[[3]] + x[[1 + 2]];
MemberQ[f[x], x[[1]]] // Quiet

(*  True  *)
```

Quiet is necessary here, since Mma does not know that `x` has a structure and gives warnings otherwise. It is not necessary, if you have previously already defined `x` as an object with the structure, say, a list.

Have fun!

Comment: Edit: Wait, actually, this doesn't seem to work... `f[x_] := x[[1]] + x[[3]] + x[[1 + 2]];` `MemberQ[f[x], x[[3]]] // Quiet`... why?

Comment: @Mehrdad Well, generally it is better to allow Mma to give warnings. Otherwise one may easily miss an error. But here it is quite clear why the warnings appear and that it is no problem.

Comment: Update: seems like (not) `FreeQ` is actually the right thing, not `MemberQ`?

Comment: @Mehrdad It is because `FullForm[f[x]] // Quiet` returns `Plus[Part[x, 1], Times[2, Part[x, 3]]]` so there is a multiplication there. One can repair it as follows: `MemberQ[f[x], a_*x[[3]]] // Quiet`.

Comment: Cool, thanks!!!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Downvalues` and `HoldPattern` to do this without `Quiet`.

```
FreeQ[DownValues@f, HoldPattern@x[[3]]]
(* False *)

FreeQ[DownValues@f, HoldPattern@x[[7]]]
(* True *)
```

`DownValues` returns the definition with `HoldPattern` so you need hold the pattern you are searching for in order to pattern match.

Hope this helps.